# Multitoc Package: Center title

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to center the title of a 2 column table of contents using the multitoc package. I have searched and read multitoc docs but cannot figure this one out.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Question 1}
\section{Question 2}
\section{Question 3}
\section{Question 4}
\section{Question A1}
\section{Question A2}
\section{Question A3}
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC EXAMPLE]

Thanks

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg Hi, updated with more info

Comment: @YoungGrandpa Nice user name. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest fix is

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % don't allow tocloft to manage toc titles
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Table of contents}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect thanks, had tried `\centering` before but not `[titles]` option